# Monkeypatch PEP 461 in Python 3.0-3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is is possible to monkeypatch [PEP 461](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0461/) functionality in to Python 3.0-3.4?

(I'm working on porting [dulwich](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dulwich/0.9.5) to python 3, and as it has a lot of protocol and file format code, it relies heavily on byte formatting.)

Comment: Not for byte-literals, no. Which is the point of the PEP.

Answer (score 0):

To monkeypatch it in, you would need to assign a relevant function to `bytes.format`. Trying it with a dummy function does this:

```
>>> bytes.format = lambda *s: None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'bytes'
```

So, no, you can't do this. You would need to modify the C code that creates the `bytes` class - at which point, you might as well just apply the patch from the relevant bug.